# Formally understanding "Replacing $(D^n, \partial D^n)$ by the equivalent pair $(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$"

Tags: algebraic-topology

In example 2.23 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology it states:

> Let us find explicit cycles representing generators of the infinite
> cyclic groups $H_n(D^n,\partial D^n)$ and $\tilde{H}(S^n)$.
> **Replacing $(D^n, \partial D^n)$ by the equivalent pair $(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$,** we will show by induction on $n$
> that the identity map $i_n:\Delta^n\to \Delta^n$, viewed as a singular
> $n$-simplex, is a cycle generating $H_n(\Delta^n,\partial \Delta^n)$.

Why can we do this replacement - i.e. what, formally, does he mean by equivalent? Is it because the standard singular $n$-simplex is homeomorphic to the $n$-dimensional disk, and so they will have the same homology groups?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have that $(D^n,\partial D^n)$ is homeomorphic to $(\Delta^n,\partial\Delta^n)$, meaning that there exist a map $h \, : \, \Delta^n \to D^n$ that is continuos, with continuos inverse and such that $h(\partial\Delta^n) = \partial D^n$.